# Where are local stack variables stored in C?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have the following program in C:

```
1  #include<stdio.h>
2  
3  int main(void) {
4      int i=0;
5      for (int k=0; k<10; k++)
6          printf("Number: %d", k);
7      printf("Hello\n");
8      return 0;
9  }
```

When I run it in `gdb` it gives me a listing of all the registers, but I don't see the variable `k` in any of those reigsters. For example, in the below screenshot, I know `k=4`, but I don't see that value in any of the registers. Where would this number be stored then?

[image]

Comment: It's stored on the stack. Do you understand how the stack works on your platform/CPU?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, not really. When would an item be saved into a register (I thought that was used for arithmetic?) and when would it be on the stack? If you want to answer that in an "answer" I can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know k=4, but I don't see that value in any of the registers. Where would this number be stored then?

If you optimized the program, the value would indeed likely be stored in a register (but the program will be much harder to debug).

Without optimization, the value is stored on stack (to be precise, given the disassembly, it is stored at location `$rbp-8`), and is loaded into a register by the very next instruction (the one *before* which you have stopped).

If you do `stepi` and look at the value of `$rax`, you will find it right there.

P.S. `info locals` will give you info about local variables.

**Update:**

> What does stepi do?

It executes a single machine instruction, then stops. You can find this out by reading the manual, or by using `help stepi` GDB command.

> What/were is $rbp-8? Could you please explain a bit more about what that is and how it works?

That is something that would be covered in every introductory x86 programming book or tutorial.

Briefly, current state of the program execution can be described as a series of linked activation records or "frames". On x86 without optimization, the `$RBP` register is usually used as a frame pointer register (i.e. it points to the current frame). Locals are stored at negative offsets from the frame pointer (here, `k` is stored at offset -8).

Comment: Cool, thanks for this response. A few comments: I use `info locals` but it's also shown in the bottom-most section automatically so I don't need to. What does `stepi` do? I've heard of `c`, `n`, and `s`, but never `stepi`. What/were is `$rbp-8`? Could you please explain a bit more about what that is and how it works?

Comment: Thanks, how can you tell it's at `-8`? Is it because we have two four-byte integers, and K comes after I ?

Comment: @TagC198 I can tell it's at -8 because the current instruction is `mov -8(%rbp),%eax`, which means: take the 32-bit value stored at frame pointer - 8 and load that value into the `$RAX` register, clearing high 32-bits of it.

Comment: *but the program will be much harder to debug* This program would be easier to debug *in asm* with optimization enabled.  Especially if you just use `-O1` or `-Og`.  Then the compiler won't need 2 or 3 instructions to do what should only take 1 if it had values in regs.  Although actually this loop does so little that I only see a load into EAX then `mov %eax,%esi` as the only wasted instruction so far.